Azure Boards: Query filter by "Board Column" not working anymore
This query used to work fine until recently, and now, it suddenly does not return anything unless I remove the "Board Column" filter:

I also noticed that the Board Column is not populated in the query results:

And if you look at the board, you'll see that it has PBIs that should be returned:

Any thoughts?

To avoid cache influence, can you launch an InPrivate browser windows for a double check? If the issue persists, please open work item 10087158, show us the area path. Try to move the work item out and back to column, check again if it fixes.
